# CasperJS click on buttons is not working

Tags: jquery, click, phantomjs, casperjs

CasperJS click on buttons is not working when jQuery is explicitly injected on the page. It works otherwise.

CasperJS code:

```
casper.waitForSelector("#somethingelse1").thenClick("#somethingelse1");
```

Comment: CasperJS doesn't use jQuery to dispatch its click events. Is there already a jQuery version on the page and you're loading a different version? What version are you loading and what is already on the page? What PhantomJS version do you have?

Comment: Are you trying to use jQuery to click the buttons, or are you looking to use CasperJS's built-in methods? CasperJS does not need jQuery in order to find selectors on the page.

Comment: I have used jquery for some other purpose but then the normal click using casper is not working.

Answer (score 0):

If you are explicitly trying to click something using JQuery, the way I do it (still fairly new at casper and using JQuery) is as follows.

`casper.waitForSelector('#somethingelse1', function(){
     casper.evaluate(function(){
        JQuery('#somethingelse1').click();
     }); 
});`